# PageRequestManagerServerErrorException

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to solve some errors that are in a project I didn't created. But one I can't find the problem is:

> Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

I have a menu, and when I click on one of the items, I want to load the data.

```
protected void menu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{

List<extList> lstEH = ehs.getList(ll_id, e.Item.Value).ToList();

            if (lstEH.Count > 0)
            {
                btnExtern.Visible = false;
            }
            dvExtern.DataSource = lstEH;
            dvExtern.DataBind();
}
```

The data I want to get comes from a DB, I call a service for it.

```
public IQueryable<externeH> getList(int ll_id, string type)
        {
            try
            {
                queryE =
                    from eh in db.exth
                    from teh in db.types
                    from k in db.kla
                    where eh.TypesExterneHulp_id == teh.Id
                          && teh.Naam == type
                          && eh.ll_id == ll_id
                          && eh.Klas_id == k.Id
                    orderby eh.DatumBegin, eh.Uitleg descending
                    select eh;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            return queryE;
}
```

Sometimes it runs, sometimes it doesn't. It's always when the first menuitem is clicked. But there is no problem when I'm trying to debug it. Then it is ok.

The data is bind on a gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="dvExterneHulp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="odd" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="mGrid niceTable"
                                             OnRowDataBound="dvExterneHulp_DataBound"
                                            PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_PageIndexChanging">
```

I searched on the internet, but there can be plenty of reasons. I checked the "post" and it gets an id. There are normally 2 results in the DB for menu-item 1.

EDIT: I tried to find out where exactly goes wrong. Seems it is at the line dvExtern.Databind(); Coming closer to the exact problem..

EDIT 2: I'm not sure, but the error happens when I have a date like 1/01/0001 0:00:00. On the localhost it is always empty (not in gridview).

The problem is the date. The value in the DB is 01/01/0001. But if want to run this code, it seems to be a problem.

```
protected void dvEH_DataBound(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {


            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string datum = functies.converteerDatum(Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[5].Text));
                if (datum == "01/01/1")
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[5].Text = datum;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an invalid date conversion.

I solved it with a check before I convert the date

```
if(e.Row.Cells[5].Text == "01/01/0001 00:00:00")
{
 //SHOW NOTHING
}
else
{
 //DO CONVERT
}
```